# Why Apache VFS (SFTP) tries to switch to root directory even when not needed And how to avoid it

Tags: java, apache, sftp, apache-commons-vfs

I am using apache VFS for uploading files to sftp server. But one sftp server has a limitation that it's root directory doesn't have any permission. But the directory which is allowed for my application is let's say "/ftp/abc/". This directory is accessible using command line. But Apache VFS first tries to switch to root directory "/" which fails due to lack of permissions in my case.

**Edit:** Setting `userDirIsRoot` to true prevents vfs from switching to root directory. But in that case we have to specify path relative to user's root directory. Which means `userDirIsRoot` is either true or else you can't specify absolute path. This doesn't sound right.
**Is there a simple way, using which we can specify absolute path, without vfs trying to switch to bare root directory of base filesystem.**

Comment: I've added an update to my answer

Comment: No answer to highlighted question, right? "Is there a simple way" - it would be good to have even complicated way of doing this...

Comment: @PetrAleksandrov lol yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant source code is in `getChannel()` in `org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.sftp.SftpFileSystem`

```
Boolean userDirIsRoot = SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().getUserDirIsRoot(getFileSystemOptions());
String workingDirectory = getRootName().getPath();
if (workingDirectory != null && (userDirIsRoot == null || !userDirIsRoot.booleanValue()))
{
    try
    {
        channel.cd(workingDirectory);
    }
    catch (SftpException e)
    {
        throw new FileSystemException("vfs.provider.sftp/change-work-directory.error", workingDirectory);
    }
}
```

The issue in your case is that `getUserDirIsRoot(getFileSystemOptions())`
evaluates to true.

> Is there anyway to tell Apache VFS library not to switch to root
>   directory?

In order to *not* enter in the if statement and *not* invoke `channel.cd(workingDirectory)`, userDirIsRoot.booleanValue() should evaluate to true.

According to the [documentation](https://people.apache.org/~rgoers/commons-vfs/site/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/sftp/SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.html#setUserDirIsRoot(org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions,%20boolean)), you can set the SftpFileSystem options using `SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder`.

Example:

```
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder
.getInstance()
.setUserDirIsRoot(options, true);
```

Comment: Actually, setting it to false is the problem. Setting it to true, fixes my error, since in that case it doesn't tries to switch to root dir..

Comment: Yes I also miss-interpreted this boolean expression - in order to skip the IF the userDirIsRoot should be true

Comment: I'll add second question then, that is there anyway to prevent vfs to switch to root directory, but still be able to specify absolute directory path.

Comment: No this still doesn't work. The problem is in manager.resolveFile(). Whatever path is given in manager.resolveFile method, it tries to switch to root directory first. Which throws error.

Comment: Have you tried to debug what happens inside DefaultFileSystemManager resolveFile? I've looked at the source code of VFS 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT and I don't see calls to changing to root directory there.

Comment: No, it's same in VFS 2.2

Comment: Please see my answer, you can edit your answer to include relevant details. So that we can mark a selected answer and move on.

Comment: I've included your answer on top. The workaround looks like the first solution we've debated.

Comment: Yes, it was your proposal. I meant that you can remove the "now" irrelevant details from the answer so that it is more helpful and easier for others. E.g. the other solutions which didn't work